# How to call the method in the.so file, but i don't know the package name which produce the .so file an Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

The error is: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found. I know that's because i called `System.loadLibrary` in my project, I need to know the package name of the .so his project。How can i solve it. If some way i can get the declare method's name.

Answer (score 0):

NDK comes with [**nm**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) utility. Look for it in **toolchains** folder, matching the ABI you work with, e.g. `toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm`.

You can run

```
…-nm -D /path/to/the/existing/sharedlib.so
```

Some exported symbols will hopefully look like `Java_my_package_name_MyClass_function`. Such function is an implementation of a native method **function** in class **MyClass** in package **my.package.name**.

Unfortunately, this only helps you to reverse these names; you cannot easily reconstruct the parameters or return value of the native method. You cannot even know whether this method should be declared as **static**.

Finally, if the library exports **JNI_OnLoad** function, it can hide the native methods, and use [RegisterNatives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#RegisterNatives) to bind the native methods to C implementations dynamically.

Comment: After execute this command, i get the following, but nothing with package info<br>
0012a1f4  D v3_ocsp_crlid<br>
0012a114 D v3_ocsp_nocheck<br>
0012668c D v3_ocsp_nonce<br>
0012a0dc D v3_ocsp_serviceloc<br>
0012a3d8 D v3_pci<br>

Comment: maybe you missed the **-D** parameter to **nm**?